# How to read old Visual Source Safe repository

Tags: repository, legacy

I have an old (from 2005) Visual Source Safe repository that I need to access for research purposes.  Apparently (and for good reason) the VSS software is no longer available.  Is there any way I can read this repository?  The files seem to be in binary so no way to just dig into them directly without some sort of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, never mind, I see that you can still get the software from MSDN.